# Apache2 not reading sites-enabled/*.conf

Tags: apache-httpd, virtual-host

So I'm trying to set up my site with Apache on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have created a `mydomain.com.conf` file in `sites-available/`. It looks like this;

**mydomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.com/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason apache doesn't seem to read `mydomain.com.conf` at all, it will always default to the configuration in `000-default.conf`.

When visting my site I get a 403 Forbidden response.

1. I've enabled the site by `a2ensite mydomain.com` and reloaded Apache.
2. `apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK`

The `error.log` file for **`000-default.conf`** says

```
[Wed Sep 03 11:01:48.717652 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 5869] [client 2.71.93.10:55718] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

while the error log & access log for `mydomain.com` is empty.

My `apache2.conf` does a `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`.

The security model in `apache2.conf` looks like this;

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Either your site is empty and not having any files or it is not having any file as mentioned int he `Directory Index`.

Another possibility is the permissions. The files or the directory of your site may not have permissions for `apache's user` to access.

Comment: There is an `index.html`. See my last code snippet where I define `DirectoryIndex`'s for the `/var/www/` directory. I'll take a look at permissions.

Comment: @Unidan, I guess you're issue is solved. Please close the question by accepting my answer as correct. :D

Comment: No it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a Apache2 log message including the phrase

```
Cannot serve directory /var/www/
```

which was strange because `/var/www` wasn't mentioned anywhere in my configuration.

But the message stopped when I did something about what I thought was a completely separate warning message:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/www/www.foo.bar/docs] does not exist
```

I surmise that when a DocumentRoot directory is not entirely ready for use, a default value, `/var/www` is (silently) used instead, which causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> My `apache2.conf` does a `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

In my case changing this to `Include sites-enabled/*.conf` solved the problem.

---

Some context to this solution:
This was on a docker build (`FROM php:7.2-apache` as of 2018-12-21) where the virtual hosts file had previously been loaded without any modifications thus giving us quite a headache when it suddenly didn't. If you need to reload apache after making this change without killing the container run `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37625408/1685346) on SO).

Answer (score -1):

Deactivate `000-default` with `a2dissite` and then restart apache.